# update xampp mysql in ubuntu

Tags: apache2, mysql, xampp

i am a student, i am learning mysql.
i have installed xampp in linux and it have been running for a while according to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5CUn5wGQGg , but one day when i read the error log, it show this:

`InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade`

i tried to run `mysql_upgrade` in ubuntu terminal, or use a phpmyadmin to run the command, but neither of them works

for terminal, it shows:

```
kelvin@kelvin-linux:~/Desktop/1.16.5main_switch$ mysql-upgrade

Command 'mysql-upgrade' not found, did you mean:

  command 'mysql_upgrade' from deb mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
  command 'mysql_upgrade' from deb mariadb-server-core-10.3 (1:10.3.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

kelvin@kelvin-linux:~/Desktop/1.16.5main_switch$
```

xampp version: `libmysql - mysqlnd 8.0.6`

`Apache/2.4.47 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.0.6 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.1`

i tried to google but most of them are for windows, i am not sure whether they work for ubuntu too.

update1:

```
kelvin@kelvin-linux:~/Desktop/1.16.5main_switch$ mysql_upgrade

Command 'mysql_upgrade' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install mysql-server-core-8.0     # version 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, or
sudo apt install mariadb-server-core-10.3  # version 1:10.3.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

kelvin@kelvin-linux:~/Desktop/1.16.5main_switch$
```

Comment: Do you *need* to use XAMPP? Having a standard LAMP stack on Ubuntu is really simple to set up and will save you a lot of time and hassle in the future 

Answer (score 0):

You typed "`mysql-upgrade`", but the actual command is "`mysql_upgrade`". That's an underscore  not a minus between the words.

Comment: i typed ``mysql_upgrade`` but still... it does not do anything but say install something, did i do something wrong?